# Why is this regular expression not working ({m, n})?

Tags: python, regex

Trying to understand regular expressions and I am on the repetitions part: `{m, n}`.

I have this code:

```
>>> p = re.compile('a{1}b{1, 3}')
>>> p.match('ab')
>>> p.match('abbb')
```

As you can see both the strings are not matching the pattern. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't put a space after the comma, and the `{1}` is redundant.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it mentioned the `{1}` part also. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
p = re.compile('a{1}b{1,3}')
```

...and mind the space.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought that this could cause a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the extra whitespace in `b`.

Change:

```
p = re.compile('a{1}b{1, 3}')
```

to:

```
p = re.compile('a{1}b{1,3}')
                        ^   # no whitespace
```

and all should be well.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing some `re` behaviour that is very "dark corner", nigh on a bug (or two).

```
# Python 2.7.1
>>> import re
>>> pat = r"b{1, 3}\Z"
>>> bool(re.match(pat, "bb"))
False
>>> bool(re.match(pat, "b{1, 3}"))
True
>>> bool(re.match(pat, "bb", re.VERBOSE))
False
>>> bool(re.match(pat, "b{1, 3}", re.VERBOSE))
False
>>> bool(re.match(pat, "b{1,3}", re.VERBOSE))
True
>>>
```

In other words, the pattern `"b{1, 3}"` matches the literal text `"b{1, 3}"` in normal mode, and the literal text `"b{1,3}"` in VERBOSE mode.

The "Law of Least Astonishment" would suggest either (1) the space in front of the `3` was ignored and it matched `"b"`, `"bb"`, or `"bbb"` as appropriate [preferable] or (2) an exception at compile time.

Looking at it another way: Two possibilities: (a) The person who writes `"{1, 3}"` is imbued with the spirit of PEP8 and believes it is prescriptive and applies everywhere (b) The person who writes that has tested `re` undocumented behaviour and actually wants to match the literal text `"b{1, 3}"` and perversely wants to use `r"b{1, 3}"` instead of explicitly escaping: `r"b\{1, 3}"`. Seems to me that (a) is much more probable than (b), and `re` should act accordingly.

Yet another perspective: When the space is reached, it has already parsed `{`, a string of digits, and a comma i.e. well into the `{m,n}` "operator" ... to silently ignore an unexpected character and treat it as though it was literal text is mind-boggling, perlish, etc.

**Update** [Bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue11204) lodged.

Answer (score 2):

Do not insert spaces between `{` and `}`.

```
p = re.compile('a{1}b{1,3}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the regex with VERBOSE flag, this means most whitespace in the regex would be ignored. I think this is a very good practice to describe complex regular expressions in a more readable manner.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags) for details...

Hope this helps...

Comment: -1 Firstly, "all whitespace in the regex would be ignored" -- this is quite untrue; a literal space can be included by doing e.g. `[ ]`. Secondly, the OP's regex does NOT start behaving as he expected merely by using the VERBOSE flag; his regex needs to change -- see my answer.

Comment: @John: thanks for pointing out the error and thanks for the bug report too... I have edited my answer.